# sum numbers entered by the user in a

Tags: python

I have to write a program that calculates the sum of numbers entered by the user until the user types 'done' and display: how many numbers (elements) the user entered, the sum of these numbers and the average. So far I managed to calculate the numbers count, but my program does not display the sum of the numbers entered. Instead, it displays the last number entered. Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong? How to do that?

```
count = 0

while True:
    n=input('enter a number: ')
    if n== 'done':
        break
    count=count + 1
    if int(n) >= 0:
        s=0 + int(n)






print(count)
print(s)
```

Comment: Replace `s=0 + int(n)` with `s += int(n).`

Comment: [how-to-debug-small-programs/](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this line `s=0 + int(n)`. This means that it will reset `s` to `n` every loop. You want to replace that with `s = s + int(n)` or `s += int(n)`.

I also made some changes to avoid other errors which will pop up.

This means that `DONE` will also register as `done`.

```
if n.lower() == 'done':
    break
```

To stop errors being thrown when a non-integer is enter you want to use some error handling.

```
try:
    n = int(n)

except ValueError as e:
    continue
```

**Final Piece**

```
count, s = 0, 0

while True:
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    
    if n.lower() == 'done':
        break
    
    count += 1

    try:
        n = int(n)

    except ValueError:
        continue

    if n >= 0:
        s += n

print(count, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not initializing the sum before entering the loop.
Add s=0 before the loop just like count = 0
Change s=0 + int(n) ==> s+=int(n)

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You're not accumulating your sum as you reset `s` with every new number entered.
Just add your new number to `s`

```
if int(n) >= 0:
    s += int(n)
```

`s` should be initialized along with `count` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

last line:

```
 s=0 + int(n)
```

should be:

```
 s=s + int(n)
```

and you should initialize `s` before `while` loop:

```
s = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you add s=0 at the beginning and then change s = 0+int(n) to s += int(n)

```
count = 0
s = 0
while True:
    n=input('enter a number: ')
    if n== 'done':
        break
    count=count + 1
    if int(n) >= 0:
        s += int(n)    
print(count)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
Sum = 0
Count = 0
Input = input("enter a number: ")
while Input != "Done":
    Sum = Sum + int(Input)
    Count = Count + 1
    Input = input("enter a number: ")

print(Sum)
print(Count)
```